# How to sort column A uniquely based on descending order of column B in unix/per/tcl?

Tags: perl, unix, tcl

I have  a csv file like the one below.

```
Column A, Column B
cat,30
cat,40
dog,10
elephant,23
dog,3
elephant,37
```

How would i uniquely sort column A, based on largest corresponding value on 
column B?

The result I would like to get is,

```
Column A, Column B
cat,40
elephant,37
dog,10
```

Comment: No quoted fields, no commas in fields?

Comment: Which language are you going to use? Asking for it in multiple languages is a good reason to close this question…

Answer (score 3):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2nr filename | awk -F, '!a[$1]++'
Column A, Column B
cat,40
dog,10
elephant,37
```

if you want your specific output it needs little more coding because of the header line.

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2nr filename | awk -F, 'NR==1{print "999999\t"$0;next} !a[$1]++{print $2"\t"$0}' | sort -k1nr | cut -f2-
Column A, Column B
cat,40
elephant,37
dog,10
```

Another alternative with removing header upfront and adding it back at the end

```
$ h=$(head -1 filename); sed 1d filename | sort -t, -k1,1 -k2nr | awk -F, '!a[$1]++' | sort -t, -k2nr | sed '1i'"$h"''
```

Answer (score 1):

Perlishly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#print header row
print scalar <>;
my %seen;
#iterate the magic filehandle (file specified on command line or 
#stdin - e.g. like grep/sed)
while (<>) {
    chomp; #strip trailing linefeed
    #split this line on ','
    my ( $key, $value ) = split /,/;

    #save this value if previous is lower or non existant
    if ( not defined $seen{$key}
        or $seen{$key} < $value )
    {
        $seen{$key} = $value;
    }
}

#sort, comparing values in %seen 
foreach my $key ( sort { $seen{$b} <=> $seen{$a} } keys %seen ) {
    print "$key,$seen{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've +1'd karakfa's answer.  It's simple and elegant.

My answer is an extension of karakfa's header handling.  If you like it, please feel free to +1 my answer, but "best answer" should go to karakfa. (Unless of course you prefer one of the other answer! :] )

If your input is as you've described in your question, then we can recognize the header by seeing that $2 is not numeric.  Thus, the following does not take the header into consideration:

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2nr filename | awk -F, '!a[$1]++'
```

You might alternately strip the header with:

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2nr filename | awk -F, '$2~/^[0-9]+$/&&!a[$1]++'
```

This slows things down quite a bit, since a regex may take longer to evaluate than a simple array assignment and numeric test. I'm using a regex for the numeric test in order to permit a `0`, which would otherwise evaluate to "false".

Next, if you want to keep the header, but print it first, you can process your output at the end of the stream:

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2nr filename | awk -F, '$2!~/^[0-9]+$/{print;next} !a[$1]++{b[$1]=$0} END{for(i in b){print b[i]}}'
```

Last option to achieve the same effect without storing the extra array in memory would be to process your input a second time.  This is more costly in terms of IO, but less costly in terms of memory:

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2nr filename | awk -F, 'NR==FNR&&$2!~/^[0-9]+$/{print;nextfile} $2~/^[0-9]+$/&&!a[$1]++' filename -
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible Tcl solution:

```
# read the contents of the file into a list of lines
set f [open data.csv]
set lines [split [string trim [chan read $f]] \n]
chan close $f

# detach the header
set lines [lassign $lines header]

# map the list of lines to a list of tuples
set tuples [lmap line $lines {split $line ,}]

# use an associative array to get unique tuples in a flat list
array set uniqueTuples [concat {*}[lsort -index 1 -integer $tuples]]

# reassemble the tuples, sorted by name
set tuples [lmap {a b} [lsort -stride 2 -index 0 [array get uniqueTuples]] {list $a $b}]

# map the tuples to csv lines and insert the header
set lines [linsert [lmap tuple $tuples {join $tuple ,}] 0 $header]

# convert the list of lines into a data string
set data [join $lines \n]
```

This solution assumes a simplified data set where there are no quoted elements. If there are quoted elements, the `csv` module should be used instead of the `split` command.

Another solution, inspired by the Perl solution:

```
puts [gets stdin]
set seen [dict create]

while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    lassign [split $line ,] key value
    if {![dict exists $seen $key] || [dict get $seen $key] < $value} {
        dict set seen $key $value
    }
}

dict for {key val} [lsort -stride 2 -index 0 $seen] {
    puts $key,$val
}
```

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Another perl

```
perl -MList::Util=max -F, -lane '
    if ($.==1) {print; next}
    $val{$F[0]} = max $val{$F[0]}, $F[1];
} {
    print "$_,$val{$_}" for reverse sort {$val{$a} <=> $val{$b}} keys %val;
' file
```